# Calling php mySQL update through ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I think this is simple question. I'm new to jQuery. I'm trying to make script, so that when you click on image, ajax will call php file which will update mySQL database.
**My script:**

```
<script>
function update(){      
        var request = $.ajax({
        url: "insert.php",
        type: "GET",            
        dataType: "html"
    });

    request.done(function(msg) {
        $("div.recen").html(msg);          
    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
    });
}; 
</script>
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="recen">
            <img src="./smile.png" class="pic" onclik="update()" /> 
</div>
```

**PHP file:**

```
<?php
$var='123';

$url='localhost';
$user='root';
$password='';

$sql=mysql_connect($url,$user,$password);
mysql_select_db('database');

$query="UPDATE table SET var='".$var."';";
if(mysql_query($query)) echo '<b>Done.</b>';
else echo mysql_error();
?>
```

For some reason, there is absolutely no response. Database remains the same and html page doesn't change a bit. Is there something wrong with the code, or I just can't update database through ajax?

Comment: Just a note you can use $query = "UPDATE table SET var='$var' "; because you dont need to escape the quotes since " string means it can expect variables inside. A string started with ' does not look for variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think somthing wrong in your query

try this

```
   $query="UPDATE table SET var='".$var."' ";
                                          ^^----remove this `;`
```

change this

```
 if(mysql_query($query)) echo '<b>Done.</b>';
 else echo mysql_error();
```

to

```
 if(mysql_query($query)){ echo '<b>Done.</b>';}
 else {echo mysql_error();}
```

there is no `onclik` in javascript instead use `onClick`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your HTML code. Your attribute should be `onclick` not `onclik`.

```
<img src="./smile.png" class="pic" onclick="update()" />
```